# Electron Blank Screen Error When Referencing Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron, renderer

**Good afternoon all,**

I am trying to import some React components from another application of mine, into my new `Electron` app.  On the new Electron app, I changed aspects of index.html, so that I can reference ‘root’ in my App.js component(which I imported from my react-app to the electron app). I also imported my index.js from my react app into my new electron app, and nested it in the src file.

**The Problem:**

I am currently getting back a blank screen, and am not sure why. It might be that i referenced some files incorrectly, or a routing issue,  but I’m not certain.
**(Picture of Screen Attached Below)**

[image]

#### *File Directory:*

[image]

## The Code:

#### **`App.js`**:

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";
import NavbarA from './src/components/NavbarA';



function App() {
 
  return (
  <div>
      <Router>
      <NavbarA/>
    </Router>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### **`Main.js`**

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

#### **`Index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <title>Spotify</title>
    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./App.js>"></script>
</html>
```

#### **`Index.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';



ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

#### **`Package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "firebase": "^9.7.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.3.1",
    "react-is": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Let Me Know What You Think!

Best,

-Zpo

Comment: Are there any console errors/warnings? Is the issue `NavbarA` component is not rendering? Have you tried rendering something simpler like plain text in the `App` component? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: No there are no errors shown(onVsCode at least), that is the confusing part. I tried rendering some plain <h1> text in the App component, with and without the router elements, and I still got the same result. I am not receiving any console warnings because Electron.js operates out of a new window, not on a web-browser. I'm not sure of the correct procedure on how to see the errors on an electron window. Furthermore being as it is a new language, I have not the slightest clue as to what kind of debugging procedure I am supposed to do with it.

Comment: Is it possible that I am rendering my components the wrong way?

Comment: AFAIK Electron apps are still built using a chromium engine, so I believe you should have some browser development tools available. Try F12 or whatever the shortcut is to open them same as in Chrome. I'm not versed much in Electron, but for the React code I don't see any overt issues, so perhaps the issue lies in how you are configuring or building Electron.

Comment: Thank You! I see, you previously mentioned that you are not an expert on Electron code. However being that you know a lot about Router, is it possible that Electron's router is different than React router?

Comment: I don't think so. Electron is basically an app container with a webview. You are still only using `react-router-dom` according to your package.json file.

Comment: Oh Okay, so where or how would you recommend I get the best advice on this question?

Comment: Question already has the `Electron` tag. Maybe someone more experienced in that tag comes along. Offering bounties is one way to help draw attention to your post if it's not getting much action. If you have your code hosted in a public repo, like github, it might make it easier for someone to pull your code locally and build the app and try some more in-depth debugging/investigation. Can you share a link to it in your post here?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and including

`import * as React from 'react';`

in the component -- NavbarA in your case -- solved my issue.